# Android relative layout children sizes

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout inside linear layout, inside relative layout i have a image view and glsurface stacked on top of it, i want glsurface to have same size as imageview, how to accomplish this task??

```
            <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <com.zibi.ResizableImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:src="@drawable/notepad" />

                <com.zibi.zGLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceviewclass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </com.zibi.travelersnotepad.zGLSurfaceView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `layout_align*` attributes. TextView will cover ImageView. [More about relative layout attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AFFF"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
        android:text="sample text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use RelativeLayout to force size properties for children views inside it.
If you dont have a particular need for it, you can use LinearLayout instead and give both views the same weight:

```
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <com.zibi.ResizableImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:src="@drawable/notepad" />

            <com.zibi.zGLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceviewclass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0">

            </com.zibi.travelersnotepad.zGLSurfaceView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "i have a image view and glsurface stacked on top of it", you cant stack one view on top of other in linear_layout, thats why i am using relative one, and i want glsurface to have same size as imageview